# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "COLUMNS"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I do not understand what the problem is:

> ORA-06550: line 13, column 57: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "COLUMNS"

```
declare

    cursor rec_tab is select table_name, COUNT(column_name) columns
    from user_tab_columns
    group by table_name;
    num_row number(6);

begin

    for ind_tab in rec_tab loop
    execute IMMEDIATE 'select COUNT(*) from '||ind_tab.table_name into num_row;
    dbms_output.put_line
        (RPAD(ind_tab.table_name,30)||' '||RPAD(ind_tab.columns,6)||num_row);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: `COLUMNS` is a PLSQL [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm). Use a different name for the column alias like `column_count`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"COLUMNS"` instead of `columns` here:

```
(RPAD(ind_tab.table_name,30)||' '||RPAD(ind_tab."COLUMNS",6)||num_row);
```

---

Another problem may by here: `num_row number(6);`, because this allows for storing a number up to 999.999 only, you will get an error when some table will have more rows.